# Bundle Jre downloaded as maven dependency with Install4J

Tags: install4j

I am using maven to build my install4J project. I am downloading `jre.tar.gz`  into my project using a Maven dependency. I want to bundle this Jre with Install4J.

I have created a compiler variable `bundleJRE` which is the path to the `jre.tar.gz` file, and I created the installer executable.

While installing on a non-java machine, I get an invalid JRE error. Do I need anything else to be configured? How can I bundle this?

Comment: Improve readability and formatting

Comment: Where did you get the .tar.gz file from? Is it a file downloaded from the nistall4j IDE or created with the install4j IDE? Is the JRE applicable for the platform you're running the installer on? What error message do you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same way to build our installer with maven. If the jre is packed correctly ensure the search sequence for the JRE is set to the installation folder first (or only). You can configure that in the "*General Settings -> Java Version*" configuration tab. We only added the installation folder and deleted all the other entries. Also ensure the minimum java version matches with your bundled one.